# MongoDB: Issue querying for only a specific subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB (and stackoverflow) - I've been trying to build real-time analytics with Mongo + Node.js.

I've created a document structure following the example at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/, but now I'm unable to query for just the "second" value with a given DateTime - I think the entire document is being returned because there is only one parent object. My structure looks like this, with only one document in the collection:

"hour" -> "minute" -> "second": value

```
doc:{
    "0": {
        "0": {
            "0": 0,
            "1": 0,
            "2": 0,
            "3": 0...
             }
         }    
}
```

I've been looking into aggregate $unwind and $(projection), and I've created a string like "12.22.59" ("hh.mm.ss"), but I have no idea where to start.

I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: As per my guess you just want that second value to be returned right, you can achieve this using find query using projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries in MongoDB always match the whole document that has the matching fields, whether those fields are arrays, embedded in subdocuments, etc. You always query for the whole document, but you can use [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to return just a part of the matching document. To return just the second value from your nested structure (as I interpret what that means), you would do

```
db.collection.find({ // your query }, { "_id" : 0, "0.0.1" : 1 })
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you're looking for. If not, could you edit the question to identify exactly what you want to be returned and let me know this isn't right with a comment?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. However, I decided to go with a more readable schema, which made it easier for me to query. Thanks!